# Twitter Bootstrap Popover does not appear immediately

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, popover

```
<td><span data-bind="text: ID, event: { mouseover: $parent.displayHearingsCaseID }" class="hearingIDCell"></span></td>
```

On the mouseover event of above table cell, I am calling displayHearingsCaseID function that displays the popover.

```
$(event.currentTarget).popover({ content: caseIDString, trigger:'hover',title: "Case ID" });
```

But I notice that, on hovering the table cell multiple times, the popover appears. Why is it not appearing immediately ?

event is the parameter passed to displayHearingsCaseID function by knockout and caseIDString is calculated for every row inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow trigger:'hover' was not working. With trigger:'click', the popover appears immediately on mouseover event of the table cell. But I had to hide the previously displayed popover while using hover : 'click'.

```
vm.displayHearingsCaseID = function (hearing, event) {
        if (hearing.CaseIDs() == null) return;
        $(event.currentTarget).popover({ content: hearing.CaseIDs(), trigger: 'click', title: "Case ID" }).mouseout(function (e) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        });

   };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample javascript code to show popover,

```
        $(function () {
            var showPopover = function () {
                $(this).popover('show');
            }
            , hidePopover = function () {
                $(this).popover('hide');
            };

            $('#tbName').popover({
                content: 'Enter first three letters of name for search',
                trigger: 'hover',
                placement:'top'
            })
            .focus(showPopover)
            .blur(hidePopover)
            .hover(showPopover, hidePopover);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

@user2585299 answer got me headed in the right direction, but it makes a little more sense if you use the 'manual' trigger and then explicitly 'show' the popover.

```
vm.displayPopover = function (obj, event) {
    $(event.currentTarget).popover({
        content: obj.some_attr,
        trigger: 'manual',
        title: "Title"
    }).mouseout(function (e) {
        $(this).popover('hide');
    }).popover('show');
};
```

and in your markup:

```
<span data-bind="text:foo, event:{mouseover:$parent.displayPopover}"></span>
```